# Will An EC2 Snapshot backup An Instance That Does Not Have A Volume?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-ec2

I create an instance but do not add additional storage / a volume, will a snapshot backup the instance and the changes I have made to the config or does it only backup data from the volumes?

I am making some training material and would like to do the following:

- Create an instance
- Create users
- Make a few more config/program installation changes

At this point, I would have a "clean copy".

I then would like to take a Snapshot of the state of the instance.

fool around, possibly break stuff

Then restore the instance to the "clean copy" after the instance has been created but before I started messing around.

Is this possible with snapshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clarify some terminology:

- A Snapshot can be made of an Amazon EBS volume. This makes a backup of the specific disk volume. The snapshot can be used later to create a new EBS Volume.
- Or, you can create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) of an Amazon EC2 instance. This creates an EBS Snapshot of all associated volumes and also stores some metadata about the AMI.

You can then **Launch a new Amazon EC2 instance from the AMI**. This will include a copy of the disks.

If you wish to restore the instance to the "clean copy", then it is best to **launch a new instance from the AMI** rather than trying to 'reset' the instance to an earlier state. The instance will have a different Instance ID and a different IP address, but will otherwise be the same as the instance from which the AMI was created.